# Existence of Designs

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I am familiar with Keevash's proof that provided divisibility conditions hold, $t-(n,k,\lambda)$ designs exist for all but finitely many $t,n,k,\lambda$.

My question is, given some $n,t,k$ does there exist a $t-(n,k,\lambda)$ design for some $\lambda$? I can't find any literature on this at all, and it seems unlikely to have an easy answer.

In particular, I would like to know in particular about the existence of $t-(n,t+1,\lambda)$ designs.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Given $n$,$t$, $k$ (with $0 \leq t \leq k \leq n$) you always have the existence of the trivial $t-(n,k,{n-t \choose k-t})$ design obtained by taking all possible $k$-sets as a block.

If you are only interested in nontrivial designs, because for each fixed $n$,$t$,$k$ there are only finitely many possible values of $\lambda$, it seems impossible with the current state of knowledge to say anything other than the obvious interpretation of Keevash which would say "for all but finitely many admissible values $n$,$t$, $k$, there is a $t-(n,k,\lambda)$ design for some $\lambda$."

(p.s. to my knowledge there are no known nontrivial designs with $t \geq 7$, although I have seen recursive techniques for building designs with arbitrary $t$ it is computationally difficult in practice to carry it up to this level.)